# CalCalendar issues retrieving calendar by name

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am having issues with the CalCalendar framework. I want to retrieve a previously created calendar so i can add events to it.

```
NSArray *calendarArray = [[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] calendars];

NSEnumerator *arrayEnum = [calendarArray objectEnumerator];

CalCalendar *calObj = nil;

while (calObj = [arrayEnum nextObject]) {

    NSLog(@"Calendar: %@", calObj.title);

    if (calObj.title == @"Calendar" ) {

        NSLog(@"Match");
    }

}
```

The problem is that this doesn't ever seem to match on the title, this is probably something simple but i have no idea. Output of log is below:

```
2012-05-08 20:38:53.976 Swish[52493:403] Calendar: Tasks
2012-05-08 20:38:53.976 Swish[52493:403] Calendar: Calendar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For strings comparing use `isEqualToString` instead `==`. So Your code should look like this:

```
NSArray *calendarArray = [[CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore] calendars];

NSEnumerator *arrayEnum = [calendarArray objectEnumerator];

CalCalendar *calObj = nil;

while (calObj = [arrayEnum nextObject]) {

    NSLog(@"Calendar: %@", calObj.title);

    if ([calObj.title isEqualToString:@"Calendar"]) {

        NSLog(@"Match");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I knew it would be something simple!